# CDH 5.9 dfs.datanode.data.dir configuration

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I've installed CDH 5.9 using Cloudera Manager Installer, where I've specified directories for HDFS metadata (/dfs/nn) and actual data (/dfs/dn).

After installation HDFS works correctly and stores metadata and data in defined in Claudera Manager locations, but in /etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml there is no setting for dfs.datanode.data.dir parameter.

Running following command returns default location for data.dir:

```
# hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.datanode.data.dir
file:///tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/data.
```

Can anyone tell where in CDH5.9 I can find configuration for HDFS that reflects my setup?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Search for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` from cloudera Manager, you will get default values, from there you can change

[image]